# jackson-dataformat-xml turns @ResponseBody to XML

Tags: json, xml, maven, jackson

So I *had* a perfectly working Spring app.  Most of my controller methods are for ajax calls that return JSON via @ResponseBody with the jackson api and returns my Java POJO to JSON.

I have a need to turn XML to JSON,  so I find that Jackson has a tool for that,  and I add this to my POM to use the library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

So that I may use this:

```
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(sb.toString().getBytes());
```

But now the @ResponseBody is returning  XML and not JSON. I Remove the dependency and the controllers return JSON again.

Any way to get both?  I want the xmlMapper, and JSON from the response body.

Answer (score 10):

`jackson-dataformat-xml` appears to be registering a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with a `XmlMapper`, along with other `HttpMessageConverter`s that work with XML. If you always intended to return JSON from your controllers, you can change what `HttpMessageConverter` your app uses by overriding `configureMessageConverters`

For Spring 5.0 and above,

```
@Configuration
public class HttpResponseConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.removeIf(converter -> supportsXml(converter) || hasXmlMapper(converter));
    }

    private boolean supportsXml(HttpMessageConverter<?> converter) {
        return converter.getSupportedMediaTypes().stream()
            .map(MimeType::getSubtype)
            .anyMatch(subType -> subType.equalsIgnoreCase("xml"));
    }

    private boolean hasXmlMapper(HttpMessageConverter<?> converter) {
        return converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
                && ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)converter).getObjectMapper().getClass().equals(XmlMapper.class);
    }

}
```

For older versions of Spring, replace `implements WebMvcConfigurer` with `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: `jacson-dataformat-xml` does not work if xml mapping is removed even if `Accept header ` is supplied.  It only works for no `Accept header` or json . In all other cases 406  Not Acceptable is returned.  
It has to be removed conditionally on accept header value. I am using Spring boot 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) for an analysis of how Spring does content negotiation and allows producing either XML or JSON.

The simplest way is to add an extension at the URL: Instead of `/path/resource` use `/path/resource.json`

You may also add a `format` parameter e.g. `/path/resource?format=json` or pass an appropriate `Accept` header

Answer (score 2):

Add `Accept: application/json` to HTTP request header.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `XmlMapper` was actually inserted into the application context as an `@Bean`. The other solutions here did not work for me. It seems like one of those issues where context matters, so for people coming here from a different context than the other answerers, here's another angle: I had to insert my own `ObjectMapper`.

```
@Configuration
public class XmlMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean // me, culprit
    public XmlMapper xmlMapper() {
        return new XmlMapper();
    }

    @Bean // to make sure the rest of the application still works with JSON
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

I'm going to throw in an `@Primary` on the `ObjectMapper` one. It seems suspicious that Spring would even choose that one consistently. Since `XmlMapper` extends `ObjectMapper`, why would it not take that one, so `@Primary` won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RestTemplate`, try switching to `RestTemplateBuilder` instead, that may be the only fix you need.

See [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77315954/1246547) for a full explanation.