# Spring Rest Controller returns XML instead of JSON after Jasperreports update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I have a Spring boot project with version 2.6.4.
And after I updated the jasperreports dependency to 6.19.0 all my RestControllers returns now XML instead of JSON
Where can I change this, without changing to

```
@GetMapping(produces = {"application/json"})
```

on each method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just have same issue today, I checked with Chrome and saw it doesn't add application/json in Accept header.
My solution is create a wrapper filter:

```
@Component
public class JsonRequestHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
                if (name.equals("Accept")) {
                    Set<String> customHeaders = new HashSet<String>();
                    Enumeration<String> curHeaders = super.getHeaders(name);
                    while (curHeaders.hasMoreElements()) {
                        String header = curHeaders.nextElement();
                        customHeaders.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.concat(";").concat(header));
                    }

                    return Collections.enumeration(customHeaders);
                }
                return super.getHeaders(name);
            }
        };

        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing the dependency on jackson-dataformat-xml also fixes the issue. I think it is a Jasper Reports bug (still present in 6.20.0) anyway and I prefer not to add custom source code for it:

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>6.20.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Any idea why it works or what in Jasper is actually the root issue?

Comment: I have not been looking at Jasper Reports code. My project is loading that artifact so it is probably a version mismatch issue

Comment: Looks to be an overall "issue" when jackson-dataformat-xml is on the classpath.  In our cases it just happen to be the way this got on the classpath is when Jasper added it.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752245/spring-5-jackson-dataformat-xml-forces-responsebody-with-xml
I opted to add the Request Accept header of "application/json" from the answer above because eliminating a dependency that a library added can have unknown consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Set the default type in the  configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) method.

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really want this to work, but it didn't work for me.  Still get the same issue where the response contentType is  application/xhtml+xml

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue by removing the (not used) `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` dependency.

Comment: How did you solve it. Have you an example previous/next versions of code?